# Error with ajax in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ajax is

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {                               
        var size = $('#ddlsize').val();
        var color = $('#ddlcolor').val();    
        $('#addtocart').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddTocart", "ShoppingCart")',
                data: {                                             
                    id:  '@Model.ProductId',
                    size: size,
                    color: color,                                           
                },
                dataType: "html",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Da them vao gio hang");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Co loi xay ra vui long thu lai");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in Controller

```
public ActionResult AddTocart(int id, string size, string color)
{
    Product productitem = dbcon.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault();
    var cart = ShoppingCart.Getcart(this.HttpContext);
    cart.AddtoCart(productitem, size, color);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Some time when i click in button add to cart,i see the error but it has been do an action and add to the cart.i didn't how it add product to cart when error

Comment: This should be converted to a `JsonResult` (or, better yet, a web api method) if your only interfacing it with AJAX. Then, respond with HTTP Status Codes (e.g. 200 Success)

Comment: Brad,can you give me more clear answaer,im a new MVC.show me where im was wrong please

Comment: Can some one else help me please

Comment: You could be getting this error for many reasons. Your "AddToCart" method might successfully add the record to the database, but fail and cause a 500 error at a later point. Also, your redirect might cause a 404 error. My advice would be to get this working with a plain old <form> first, to make sure nothing breaks, then start to introduce ajax calls once you are happy with it. You could also try a chrome plugin called "Postman" where you can manually send requests to the server and see responses.

Comment: hi @keith i think i forgot use httppost for my actionresult,did it?.And can you tell me how to make a transaction if fail it will not do a action in my antionresult.thank you

Comment: when the first time i submit it alsway error,I cannot resolve the problem,when i go to another page it will be success.

Comment: Without knowing more about what your code is doing, it is difficult to tell why this might error, but still update the database. Again, you are not logging the response from the server, try using this tool https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en OR stop using jquery and try using a <form> to see what the server is responding with.